# How to create button backgrounds with css

Tags: html, css

I read once how to create cross-browser rounded buttons with shadow using images, I lost my bookmarks unfortunately that's why I ask does anybody remember the technique.

There is left side picture i.e

[image]

And then very wide body image which ends up with right curved border/shadow like this :

[image]

So at the end you end up with one button which can be used with multiple sizes? I was googling this, but it seems noways everyone use css without images.

Does anybody knows how this technique is called or can refer me to the link? or give me code example, I'd appreciate any of those

Comment: Why would you want to use images over CSS? Let the older browsers have sharp corners and flat background colours! Graceful degradation!

Comment: Well, multiple HORIZONTAL sizes. Good luck having a larger call to action without multiple images. :/

Comment: @Neurofluxation: I have a ton of IE7 users, unfortunately. I can understand the need for cross-browser solutions.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that "sliding doors" can be used with more complex images than the ones in this post, things that cannot be reasonably done with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is a variation of the "Sliding Doors" technique:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/
- http://azadcreative.com/2009/03/bulletproof-css-sliding-doors/

Basically you use markup like this:

```
<button><span>Text</span></button>
```

Then style the `span` with the edge image to the side, overlapping the main background image of the parent element. Something like this:

```
button {
    background:url(main-image.png) top right no-repeat;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    width:80px;  /* with only 1 "door", you might need to set a width */
    /* other resets may be necessary */
}
span {
    background:url(left-door.png) left top no-repeat;
}
button, span {
    height:37px; /* height of your sprite */
    display:block;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqs3m/

Your results may vary depending on your sprites and the natural width of the content.

Comment: You don't really need additional elements in your markup to use sliding doors, you could also use a pseudo element.

Comment: @feeela: I may be wrong, but I don't think IE7 (for example) supports them.

Answer (score 1):

When using an image for the start and one for end of the button, these technique is called "sliding doors" and there are myriads of search results with any search engine…

For an introduction read the A List Apart article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors

But as  Neurofluxation asked you in the comment above: Why the hell would you do that years after we have multiple other methods of styling a button in CSS? The A List Apart article for example is from 2003 - which is an age in Internet terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the technique which I think you are looking for (using the same images you attached):

**HTML:**

```
​<a href="#" class="button">
  <span>Small</span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span>Large button</span>
</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
​.button {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/htUHL.png') no-repeat left top;
    padding-left: 9px;
    height: 37px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.button span {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID6nO.png') no-repeat right top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 3px;
}
.button:hover span {
    ​color: #333;
}​
```

**Link to the demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v284q/

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS properties instead of images can make your applications faster.

In this case you could just use: Border-Radius, Box-Shadow combined with a gradient background.

Here you can find a good Gradient Editor:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

How to use Border-radius and Box-shadow:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/